# word listener made with python keyboard module being triggered despite the required word not being typed

Tags: python

I've been making a script that I dub the "pissbot", made to automatically send the message "piss" after a specific amount of time, and it's been incredibly basic in the past. I've been activating it through a single hotkey - usually shift + enter - but now I wish to enable the script with a command, I'm just trying to use the word "enable" to enable the script. I've looked around the internet, trying to find examples of how the keyboard word listener works, but I couldn't find anything, so I tried to figure it out myself and learned that it requires the following:

1. a word to listen for. (here, I am using "enable")
2. a callback (I didn't really know what this was so I searched that up too and learned it's basically just a function that gets called when the requirements are met).
3. a trigger, something that tells the listener to check if the previous word is the correct word or not.

Now, I have the following code:

```
enabled = False
timer = 1
condition = False


def enable():
    global condition
    condition = True


# wsh.AppActivate("blank")

while True:
    keyboard.register_word_listener("enable", enable(), ["\n"])

    if condition:
        enabled = True

    if enabled:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        wsh.SendKeys("piss")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        wsh.SendKeys("\n")
        time.sleep(timer)
```

For all I know, this code should work perfectly fine, and typing "enable" then hitting enter should enable the script without any issues. But it doesn't, and the script is activated immediately upon starting the program, no matter what kind of keyboard input I give, even if there is no keyboard input at all.

I've tried searching for anything at all on this specific function, but I wound up with zero useful results. I really don't know where to go from here, I have zero idea how I can get this working or how I can find what's wrong with my code.

I've checked stack overflow for any questions similar to mine, but none I found match my problem.

I hope that after I post this, I don't get a message saying a question like this has been asked before, cause I've posted a question after looking for a question similar to it and not finding any, just to be told a question similar to it has already been posted.

but hey, if I do get told someone has asked this before, then I guess I'll end up getting my answer.

side note:
I know my code can be improved a lot, this is only the pissbot after all, so I'm not trying to make this the most optimized thing in the world.

Comment: first off, a fully runnable [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice, to make it easier for others to run and debug your code. Next: looking at the `keyboard` library, I believe you need to specify the **key** in the triggers, not a **character**. i.e. : try replacing `"\n"` with `"enter"`.

Comment: @Hoodlum thanks for telling me that, I'll make sure to do include that next time.
I tried replacing "\n" with "enter" just now, yet the script is still being activated instantly upon the programming starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code.

The main one is that rather than passing your `enable` callback function object to your listener you are calling it (by using the parentheses `()`) and passing its return value to the listener. The default return value in python is `None`, so nothing is happening when the listener is activated, however, every time the listener is registered, the callback function is run, causing your script to output its message prematurely.
The solution is simply to omit the parenthesis.

The other minor issues are :

- you're registering a new listener at every iteration of your loop, which is not necessary. you only need to register it once.
- you need to specify the trigger key(s), not letters/characters. For the enter/return key, this is `"enter"`, rather than `"\n`.

Below a small example of how you might get it to run :

```py
import time
import keyboard

timer = 1
enabled = False

def callback():
    global enabled
    enabled = True

# pass the callback function object, not the result of the callback function
keyboard.register_word_listener("enable", callback, ["enter"])

while True:

    if enabled:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("urine", end="")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("\n", end="")
        time.sleep(timer)
```